# Null Exception on EntityState.Detached in Asp.Net Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an user profile page which user can update it own informations.
When I'm trying to update, im getting `instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is tracked` error and i allready look around to solve this problem. I know i need to point that object as `Detached` so i can update it without taking any error in `Try-Catch` block. Let me show to you my frontend and my backend first.
Frontend :

```
<form class="mt-0" asp-action="MyProfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input asp-for="User.UserID" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserID" name="UserID">
    <input asp-for="User.UserPassword" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserPassword" name="UserPassword">
    <input asp-for="User.UserEMail" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserEMail" name="UserEMail">
    <input asp-for="User.UserToken" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserToken" name="UserToken">
    <input asp-for="User.UserRequestToken" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserRequestToken" name="UserRequestToken">
    <input asp-for="User.UserIsActive" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserIsActive" name="UserIsActive">
    <input asp-for="User.UserIsEmailConfirmed" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserIsEmailConfirmed" name="UserIsEmailConfirmed">
    <input asp-for="User.CompanyID" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.CompanyID" name="CompanyID">
    <input asp-for="User.UserRoleID" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.UserRoleID" name="UserRoleID">
    <input asp-for="User.CompanyIsAdmin" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.CompanyIsAdmin" name="CompanyIsAdmin">
    <input asp-for="User.CreatedDate" type="hidden" value="@Model.User.CreatedDate" name="CreatedDate">
    <div class="form-row mb-4">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="User.UserName"><b>Kullanıcı Adı</b></label>
            <input asp-for="User.UserName" type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Ad" name="UserName" value="@Model.User.UserName" required>
            <span asp-validation-for="User.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="User.UserSurname"><b>Kullanıcı Soyadı</b></label>
            <input asp-for="User.UserSurname" type="text" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Soyad" name="UserSurname" value="@Model.User.UserSurname" required>
            <span asp-validation-for="User.UserSurname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row mb-4">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="User.UserPhone"><b>Kullanıcı Telefonu</b></label>
            <input asp-for="User.UserPhone" type="text" class="form-control"
                  placeholder="+905555555555" minlength="11" name="UserPhone" value="@Model.User.UserPhone" required>
            <span asp-validation-for="User.UserPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="User.UserBPhone"><b>Kullanıcı İş Telefonu</b></label>
            <input asp-for="User.UserBPhone" type="text" class="form-control"
                  placeholder="+905555555555" minlength="11" name="UserBPhone" value="@Model.User.UserBPhone">
            <span asp-validation-for="User.UserBPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="MyProfile" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 btn-block">
        Update Your Informations
    </button>
</form>
```

Backend :

```
#region /*UpdateMyProfile*/
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyProfile(User user)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // That's the point where i got the null exception error
           _context.Entry(user).State =Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
            // That's the point where i got the null exception error
            user.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.ModifiedUserId = getCurrentUser();
            user.ModifiedUserType = getCurrentUserClaimRole();
            await _unitOfWorkUser.RepositoryUser.UpdateAsync(user);
            await _unitOfWorkUser.CompleteAsync();
            var log = _logging.Logging("Firma (Kullanıcı Bilgilerini) Güncelledi", "Update/Post",//
            user.UserID.ToString(), "Company-MyProfile/UpdateMyProfile", getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUserClaimRole());
            await _unitOfWorkLog.RepositoryLog.CreateAsync(log);
            await _unitOfWorkLog.CompleteAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "İşleminiz Başarısız.";
            TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var log = _logging.Logging(ex.Message, "Exception/Hata", user.UserID.ToString(),
           "MyProfile/UpdateMyProfile", getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUserClaimRole());
        _unitOfWorkLog.RepositoryLog.Create(log);
        _unitOfWorkLog.Complete();
        TempData["Message"] = ex.Message;
        TempData["JS"] = "showError();";
        return RedirectToAction("MyProfile");
    }
}
```

I point the Exception on the backend method. I Dont know why but im getting Null Exception when im trying to `Detached` the object. I dont know why im getting that error i mean its no making sense.

Comment: We see zero EF code here. Also, did you check that `user` isn't `null`? You should debug your own code and tell what actually is null. We can't do that for you.

Comment: user is not null. im sure about that and i allready watch the related objects. im believing its not an null exception error. i will let u know when i figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought that using an UoW and a generic repository is never a good idea (read this for example https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/ ) So this is code I would be using. You can modify it to UoW if you can or need

```
    var userExisted=_context.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(Id==user.Id);
     if (userExisted==null) ....exception error

     _context.Entry(userExisted).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
                
            userExisted.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            userExisted.ModifiedUserId = getCurrentUser();
            userExisted.ModifiedUserType = getCurrentUserClaimRole();

           var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

           if(result==0) ...error
```

Comment: there is a ID implementation right ? i dont have that implementation and i really dont know how to do that. can u suggest me a example github repo or some links because i allready search for it and i couldnt find it. @Serge

Comment: @BerkGarip Sorry what ID implementation means?

Comment: i solve it and u inspired of me about some ways. thank you so much  sir

Answer (score 0):

Update your Back-End code like this:-

```
//clarify code

   if (!user.IsNull())
    {
        _context.Entry(user).State =Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
    }

//clarify code
```

**UPDATE**

First of all,you have to create a `ViewModel` for your `User` model.
Assume that your ViewModel name is `UserVM`.

Now update your code like below:-

```
 try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          UserVm user1= new UserVm()
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    UserPhone= user.UserPhone,
                    
                    //and so on as needed.
                };
    if (!user1.IsNull())
    {
         _context.Entry(user1).State =Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
    }
//clarify code
```

try that,it should works.

Comment: As u can see im using ```if (ModelState.IsValid)```  and u cant controll it like that on the backend.